# Why is my dot product for 3d turning it black in the other direction?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, lighting

This is my current fragment shader's main. If I don't use lightDot in the light calculation the lighting is a nice round evenly fading white in every direction. But once I add lightDot it seems to make the other half of the object just black. 
[image: Screenshot].
To my knowledge the dot product should make the light bright when the angle between the world position and the light is close to the surface normal and make the light darker as the angle is greater.

```
void main()
{
    vec3 lightDir=normalize(lightPosition-worldPosition);

    float lightDot=dot(worldNormal,lightDir);
    float dist=distance(lightPosition,worldPosition);
    vec3 light=lightDot*materialDiffuse/(dist*dist);

    fragmentColor=vec4(pow(light.x,gamma),pow(light.y,gamma),pow(light.z,gamma),1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The dot product is signed. Just plug in some values:

```
(0,1) dot (0,1) = 1
(0,-1) dot (0,1) = -1
```

Usually in shaders you clamp at 0, because we are trying to approximate incoming light which can not be negative.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually in the model importer swapping the Y and Z axes on the geometry but not the normals. I figured this out by wondering why the X axis moving in one direction reduces the dot product as if it was moving away from the normal.